# Is there a Linux library for creating AVI files?

Tags: linux, video, embedded, avi

I need to create an app which gets raw video ***(RGB 32bits)*** data and store this data in an AVI file.
Is a "simple" library is available out there ? I'm mean low footprint as it's for an embedded project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not that small, but [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) should do the job. You don't need *all* of it.

Answer (score 2):

This should help you:
http://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/common.html

Comment: I'm a little confused about how I can generate AVI stream with V4L.
I already have a device driver to acquire video data from the board, and the device give me the address of the buffer containing video frame. 
All I need is a lib that take my video frames and put them in an AVI container.

Comment: your link is dead